# Is this SE site only for beer, or other brewing?

Tags: discussion

Would questions on making cider be appropriate here?

If not could I humbly suggest that as quite a niche topic, and not massive traffic, expanding from "beer" to "brewing" might be a good idea to consider? Many people who are into making their own beer also make cider, wine, etc so it seems a natural thing to do.

Or are there communities on SE for this already?

Comment: Oh - is this about drinking beer rather than making it?

Comment: Good question! [Last discussed here](http://meta.beer.stackexchange.com/questions/22/are-hard-ciders-on-topic), the community is in favor of cider being on-topic. Perhaps mead as well. Wine, not so much, for lack of beer ingredients such as hops. And no, this site is for questions about drinking as well as brewing, as well as storage and finding beers and anything to do with beer. However, there _is_ a more advanced SE for [Homebrewing](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/).